# JMeter - RMI vs SSH tunneling

Tags: ssh, jmeter, rmi

I am using Apache-JMeter for **distributed performance testing**.
The master & slave communicate via `Java RMI`. It works fine so far. I do not see any issues.

But in some forums/blog, I see people use **SSH Tunneling/Port forwarding** for communication between master & slave.
I tried to google to find the advantages of SSH tunneling over RMI. I could not find any.

Is the communication via SSH is faster than RMI? Could someone please clarify?

NOTE:

I am trying to find the advantages of using SSH tunneling for JMeter distributed testing over RMI. In which case we will prefer SSH tunneling ?

Comment: Just a guess: encryption.

Comment: Don't use code formatting for text that isn't code.

Comment: @EJP, Ok, I thought of highlighting. I have bolded it now.

Comment: Why? It doesn't need any emphasis. You're only making it less readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It makes sense only in case when jmeter master and slave cannot communicate directly and connection needs to be done via hopoff node or in secure environments where only one SSH port is open and you need to establish connectivity.

Comment: thanks. i was very curious if i was doing anything wrong /  i was thinking ssh tunnel is faster communication between master & slave than RMI

Answer (score 1):

The standard arrangement is based on RMI  and works fine if all the systems are in the same network.
If you need to put the systems on different networks, the you have to set up some kind of VPN  between them and in that case SSH tunneling can do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing apples and oranges. RMI is an application protocol and API. SSH tunneling is a system utility. They're not interchangeable or comparable.

Comment: Thanks. I see. I am trying to find the advantages of using SSH tunneling for JMeter distributed testing over RMI. It can be done successfully in both ways. In which case people will prefer SSH tunneling ?

Comment: I thought so. You are talking about RMI *over* SSH tunnelling. Not one or the other. You need to clarify your question if that's the case. You would use SSH tunnelling when you need to, e.g. for firewall reasons, and not otherwise.

Comment: thanks for answer. sorry for the confusion in the question..i will be careful next time.